# How can a system like Jarvis understand the commands and take actions?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, natural-language-understanding, natural-language-generation, intelligent-personal-assistants

I am looking to make an AI like [Jarvis](https://github.com/sukeesh/Jarvis). A perfect real-life example of this type of system is the simple AI that Mark Zuckerberg has recently built. [Here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/mark-zuckerberg/building-jarvis/10154361492931634) is a description of how his AI works. From what I understand, the AI understands keywords, context, synonyms, and then from there decides what to do. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvimBPJ3XGQ) is also a video of the AI in action.

I have many questions about how these systems works. Firstly, what necessary steps are required to gather the meaning of a input? Secondly, how does the system, once it extracts all of the necessary information on the input, determine what action it needs to take and what to say back to the user? Lastly, it also states that the system can learn the habits and preferences of the user. How can a system do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jarvis was built using the suite of tools that facebook developers are constantly updating. The answer to this question is that there's no simple answer; it has a lot of moving parts.

Take for example natural language processing. There are a number of sub-topics that are each considered "big" problems, such as part-of-speech recognition, coreference resolution, sentiment analysis, relationship extraction, and many more. Tools have been built to tackle these various topics, but, to my knowledge, none of them really *understand* language, but rather statistically approximate it.

In the case of Jarvis, since it is a home-automation system, it's probably built with the user-given commands in mind from the beginning, so it's not trying to understand the whole human language, it's built to do some tricks.

Just keep in mind on your journey into this space that true AI like what we imagine will have some defining features like hierarchical representations of tasks and goal-orientation. If you really get into it I'd start with reinforcement learning, or try reading through the Society of Minds.

Comment: The question was very general, so it's difficult to give a specific answer. However, although what you say about NLP and NLU seems to be valid, you should probably provide some reliable references that describe in detail one of these systems.